# What is the meaning of Tathira (تطهیرا) at end of verse 33:33?

Tags: tafseer

The end of the verse mentioned above mentions purification twice. The first mention of this word means "to purify you" and the second mention according to Arabic grammar relates to the "type" of purification.

What is that specific type of purification? Some translations have translated it as extensive purification or other types of purification. Please mention evidences or hadith to show what type of purification Allah means in this verse

> وَقَرْ‌نَ فِي بُيُوتِكُنَّ وَلَا تَبَرَّ‌جْنَ تَبَرُّ‌جَ
>   الْجَاهِلِيَّةِ الْأُولَى وَأَقِمْنَ الصَّلَاةَ وَآتِينَ الزَّكَاةَ
>   وَأَطِعْنَ اللَّـهَ وَرَ‌سُولَهُ إِنَّمَا يُرِ‌يدُ اللَّـهُ لِيُذْهِبَ
>   عَنكُمُ الرِّ‌جْسَ أَهْلَ الْبَيْتِ وَيُطَهِّرَ‌كُمْ تَطْهِيرً‌ا
>
> And abide in your houses and do not display yourselves as [was] the
>   display of the former times of ignorance. And establish prayer and
>   give zakah and obey Allah and His Messenger. Allah intends only to
>   remove from you the impurity [of sin], O people of the [Prophet's]
>   household, and to purify you with [extensive] purification. 
>   http://tanzil.net/#33:33

*Please note the evidence or proof for type of purification is needed and not only the personal idea of an interpreter even if he is a famous interpreter.*

Comment: i've edited the question to clarify the english. please check if i've missed out any detail.

Answer (score 2):

This is an Arabic Language way of confirmation.

The word تطهيراً is, in matter of I'rab is called مفعول مطلق, it can be used for:

- **To further confirm the verb**, like (but not identical to) the difference between saying: "I will clean the floor" and "I will clean up the floor", both mean cleaning, but the latter sentence has more confirmation in meaning. المفعول المطلق is used for confirmation by adding the infinitive of the verb. **And this is the case we have in the Ayah you mentioned**, تطهيراً is مفعول مطلق, it's an infinitive of يطهر, it's used for further confirmation and expressing a stronger meaning:

  > وَقَرْنَ فِي بُيُوتِكُنَّ وَلَا تَبَرَّجْنَ تَبَرُّجَ الْجَاهِلِيَّةِ الْأُولَىٰ ۖ وَأَقِمْنَ الصَّلَاةَ وَآتِينَ الزَّكَاةَ وَأَطِعْنَ اللَّهَ وَرَسُولَهُ ۚ إِنَّمَا يُرِيدُ اللَّهُ لِيُذْهِبَ عَنكُمُ الرِّجْسَ أَهْلَ الْبَيْتِ وَ**يُطَهِّرَكُمْ تَطْهِيرًا**
  >
  > Sahih International Translation
  >
  > And abide in your houses and do not display yourselves as [was] the display of the former times of ignorance. And establish prayer and give zakah and obey Allah and His Messenger. Allah intends only to remove from you the impurity [of sin], O people of the [Prophet's] household, and to purify you with [extensive] purification.
  >
  > [[Surat Al-'Aĥzāb:33]](http://quran.com/33/33)
- **To specify the type**, the same ayah above contains this type at: وﻻ تبرجن تبرج الجاهلية الأولى, you can see that He specifies the type of تبرج (display or, easier meaning, make up) in the words after it "الجاهلية الأولى", so He specified the type with مفعول مطلق and a word after it that mentions the type. The specification of type *must* have a type mentioned after it.
- **To specify the count (or amount)**, like in this ayah:

  > وَحُمِلَتِ الْأَرْضُ وَالْجِبَالُ فَدُكَّتَا دَكَّةً وَاحِدَةً
  >
  > Sahih International Translation
  >
  > And the earth and the mountains are lifted and leveled with one blow -
  >
  > [[Surat Al-Ĥāqqah:14]](http://quran.com/69/14).

  You can see there is دكتا دكة, the verb is دكّ (attached to it تا) and the infinitive is دكْ (feminized with ة), and then He specifies how many دكة (blow is a close translation) are made with the word واحدة which mean "one". So He specified the count using مفعول مطلق and a word for the number.

Hope that makes it clear.

Comment: interpreting تطهیرا to strong cleaning is only an personal idea without any proof. in fact you did not answer the question. question needs for proof and not only personal idea of an translator or interpreter. تطهیرا means a specific type of cleaning. it can be strong cleaning or other type of cleaning.

Comment: @BattleofKarbala what you've said in your comment about your post applies to the comment itself too, as تطهيراً comes from the verb طَهَّرَ to purify and to clean and means purifcation or cleaning and may also refer to the act of cleaning or purifying itself the reason for mentioning it after the verb is only to emphasize this act. Pretending there's a specific way of purification is far fetched and needs strong evidences!